# Converting fixed container to fluid.... how do I set the height?

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

***Update:**
Sorry for the confusion everyone... I actually meant to ask what the best practise would be for scaling the height of a div? If I convert 200px width, and 300px height to a scalable div, it will be 20% in width. How would I be able to scale the height? Like... how do I get it to stay in proportion without using px? Is there like a way to set the height based on the width maybe? Something that says, use 50% of the width size or something like that? I just need a way to keep the div in proportion while the div resizes in width...*

---

I have a parent container which needs to remain in fixed pixels. However, I would like all the child div's to be fluid.
But I'm a little bit confused when it comes to converting the height though.

Let's say my code used to be like this:

```
#parent {width: 1000px;}
#child {width: 200px; height: 300px;}
```

And my new code to turn the child into fluid, is this:

```
#parent {width: 1000px;}
#child {width: 20%;}
```

Is there any way to set the height of the child in percentage (to be equal to 300px in this example), without setting a height to the parent?

Comment: Your questions confuses me: you want the height of the child to be a percentage of an unknow height? xx% of unknow = unknown, no?

Comment: use fix width, because people may think you are referring to `position: fixed` ;)

Comment: This also confuses me, you answered your own question didn't you? Like ptriek said, percentage of unknown height = unknown... Simple as that.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys... I just updated my post.

Comment: @dadadey: Still is not clear, what do you mean with *keep the div in proportion while the div resize in width*. Anyway, via CSS is impossible so set the height like 60% of width, in that case you will need to use Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not clear enough, but you need to know that as long as the parent element is positioned and with `height: auto`, you can set the child's height to 100%:

```
#parent {
    height:auto; 
    width: 1000px; 
}
#child {
    height:300px; 
    width: 30%; 
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7wxqE/

#### Further reading:

Now, if you want more than one floated child inside the parent, let's say 3 columns you will need to float the child and parent and add `position: relative` to the parent and children:

```
#parent {
    height:auto; 
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px; 
    float: left;
}
#child {
    height:100%; 
    width:30%; 
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4ntn5/

Answer (score -1):

i don't know how to do it in css, but i can do it in javascript

1. get the width of the parent elemet
2. calculate the percentage of the width
3. then apply the calculated value to the child element's height.

like

```
var parentWidth = $("#parent").width();
var childHeight = Number(parentWidth) * 0.30;
$("#child").height(childHeight);
```

i thing there is no technique in css to apply height based on the width of the parent element. I mean I didn't get from anywhere.